# How can I get the phone native font size in react native?

Tags: react-native, fonts

I need to get the phone native font size (set in accessibility on ios and screen settings on android). is there a way to get that parameter?

I couldn't find anything online.

I need that because whenever a user changes his phone native font size the font in the app also getting bigger(which is just fine! I want to support that) but the elements that contains it doesn't.
So I need that parameter to handle the container elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [react-native-device-info](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-device-info) as it gives you a function getFontScale() for getting device font size in android and ios

Comment: That was it! :) not getting the font size but the ratio. which is enough for handle the styles of the elements. Thanks!